# Calculation Issue in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble figuring out where my issue with this code is.  My calculations work perfectly until the last case (CASE IS > 8), which continuously returns a 0.00 as the result.  I'm sure its something small that a newbie like me is missing due to lack of experience.  Thank you for your help!

> ' Declaration of Variable
>
> ```
> Convert.ToInt32(txtAttending.Text)
> Dim decAttending = txtAttending.Text
>
> If IsNumeric(txtAttending.Text) And txtAttending.Text <= 16 Then
>     Select Case txtAttending.Text
>         Case Is = 1
>             decCost = 695 * decAttending
>         Case 2 To 4
>             decCost = 545 * decAttending
>         Case 5 To 8
>             decCost = 480 * decAttending
>         Case Is > 8
>             decCost = 395 * decAttending
>     End Select
> Else
>     MsgBox("Please double check that your input is a number not greater than 16", , "Input Error")
>
> End If
>
> If radYes.Checked = True Then
>     decFinalCost = (decCost - (decCost * 0.15))
>     lblRepeatDiscount.Visible = True
>     decDiscount = (decCost * 0.15)
>     lblDiscount.Text = decDiscount.ToString("C")
>     lblTotalPrice.Text = decFinalCost.ToString("C")
>
> Else
>     decFinalCost = decCost
>     lblTotalPrice.Text = decFinalCost.ToString("C")
> End If
> ```

Comment: And you are sure decAttending is not 0?

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Case Else
        decCost = 395 * decAttending
```

Comment: What will be returned if the user enters a negative number?

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToInt32(txtAttending.Text)` does not convert the text in-place, as your first line of code seems to assert; this is a no-op. `txtAttending.Text` has type `System.String`, and will always have that type.

Your case statement should look more like this:

```
If IsNumeric(txtAttending.Text) Then

    Dim decAttending = Convert.ToInt32(txtAttending.Text)

    Select Case decAttending
        Case Is = 1
            decCost = 695 * decAttending
        Case 2 To 4
            decCost = 545 * decAttending
        Case 5 To 8
            decCost = 480 * decAttending
        Case 9 To 16
            decCost = 395 * decAttending
    End Select
Else
    MsgBox("Please double check that your input is a number not greater than 16", , "Input Error")
```

This version always uses the `System.Int32` variable `decAttending` when doing numeric operations.

Comment: I have updated based on your suggestions, and still ALL the calculations except the last (9 to 16) are working.  I'm getting a zero for the last option and not sure what I have wrong?

Comment: In that case, it's time to start debugging. You could start by adding a MsgBox(decAttending) above the `decCost = 395 * decAttending` line

Comment: I have added the msgbox line as suggested, and it doesn't return anything...  I'm stumped.

Comment: Add this as another case:  Case Else      MsgBox("Fell through to the Else case!", , "Logic error")

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you convert the text to a number first? I'd change these lines:

```
If IsNumeric(txtAttending.Text) And Val(txtAttending.Text) <= 16 Then
    Select Case Val(txtAttending.Text)
```

Notice that this snippet has no effect: `Convert.ToInt32(txtAttending.Text)`, you're converting a text to an integer, but the result is not being stored in a variable.

Also, what happens if the number is <= 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from mentioned advices, it seems great, but
are you sure that all code you did is written, or is there a thrown code that manipulate 
Diccost,or disattending,please assure us that.